# resources in VB2005.net?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

In short my program plays a random embedded audio file when a timer runs out, is there a way to refer to the my.resources files as an array and use them that way rather than needing to know the exact file name of the resource?

Comment: is this a web application, or a windows application?

Comment: windows app, basically an eggtimer with a screensaver and sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this on a windows application, but I had to do the same thing for a web application, and I used the following code to achieve that:

VB version:

```
' get a reference to the current assembly
Dim a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

' get a list of resource names from the manifest
Dim resNames = a.GetManifestResourceNames()

'Generate a random number
Dim randomNumber = YourRandomNumberGenerator()

'Get the file name using the randomNumber
Dim randomFileNameFromResource = resNames(randomNumber)

'Get the contents of the file:
Dim sr = New StreamReader(a.GetManifestResourceStream(randomFileNameFromResource))
Dim fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

C# version

```
        // get a reference to the current assembly
        var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        // get a list of resource names from the manifest
        var resNames = a.GetManifestResourceNames();

        //Generate a random number
        var randomNumber = YourRandomNumberGenerator();

        //Get the file name using the randomNumber
        var randomFileNameFromResource = resNames[randomNumber];

        //Get the contents of the file:
        var sr = new StreamReader(
              a.GetManifestResourceStream(randomFileNameFromResource ));
        var fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I would think the position of the file in the array would change over time though if more embedded resources get added, but i guess it would not matter for you since you are picking a random one anyway.

Comment: Assembly, doesn't appear to exist directly in vb2005, however i found it i think My.Application.Info.LoadedAssemblies(0).GetFiles 
there, so you weren't too far off

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer for me in vb2005 is Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
theres also a get stream function in there, thank you Roberto for that